# Manipulating width and height of rows and cells in iTextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, height, width, itext

I have used the following code to fill my PdfPTable:

```
  public PdfPTable GetTable(List<hsp_Narudzbe_IzdavanjeFakture4_Result> proizvodi)
    {
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(5);
        table.WidthPercentage = 100F;
        table.DefaultCell.UseAscender = true;
        table.DefaultCell.UseDescender = true;
        Font f = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 13);
        f.Color = BaseColor.WHITE;
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Stavke narudžbe: ", f));
        cell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.BLACK;
        cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        cell.Colspan = 5;
        table.AddCell(cell);
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            table.AddCell("Redni broj");
            table.AddCell("Proizvod");
            table.AddCell("Cijena");
            table.AddCell("Šifra proizvoda");
            table.AddCell("Kolicina");
        }
        table.DefaultCell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY;
        table.HeaderRows = 3;
        table.FooterRows = 1;
        int broj = 0;
        table.DeleteLastRow();


        foreach (hsp_Narudzbe_IzdavanjeFakture4_Result p in proizvodi)
        {
            broj++;
            table.AddCell(broj.ToString());
            table.AddCell(p.Naziv);
            table.AddCell(p.Cijena);
            table.AddCell(p.Sifra);
            table.AddCell(p.Kolicina.ToString());
        }
        float[] widths = { 15.00F, 15.00F,15.00F,15.00F};
        table.GetRow(1).SetWidths(widths);


        return table;
    }
```

Little explanation of code:

broj++; represents the row number which gets incremented each time a new row is added. That way I get the number for each row.

Now my question is: how can I manipulate width of the first column (which represents the row number). I have tried the following code:

```
float[] widths = { 15.00F, 15.00F,15.00F,15.00F};
table.GetRow(1).SetWidths(widths);
```

Can someone help me out with this ?

Comment: Column widths are defined for the *whole table*. You *can not* and **should not** change the width of a column at the level of a single row. Please rephrase your question so that we get a better understanding of the nature of your question. What do you want to achieve? Maybe you want to nest a table in a cell that spans all columns...

Comment: Well first I would like the text in the cells to be in the center of the cells, not on the left side as it is right now. Second I would like that the first row has lowest width, because each cells in it contains just a number (1,2,3,4...), other cells in 2,3,4 and 5th row contain text (and they should have longer width). I hope I rephrased the question so that you can understand it now.

P.S. I can't thank you enough for your answer yesterday on my question, you sir are a genius :)!

Comment: OK, give me some time and I'll see if I can make a simple example.

Comment: Okay sir. Thanks a lot once again!

Comment: It is custom to *accept* the answer that was most useful. If you do not accept an answer, it is as if the question didn't get a correct answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Combining your original post and your comment, I see two questions:

1. You want to create a table where the first column isn't as wide as the other columns.
2. You want the content in those columns to be center-aligned.

I have written a small sample named [ColumnWidthExample](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/tables/ColumnWidthExample) that should result in such a PDF:

[image]

This is the Java code that produces this PDF:

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();
    float[] columnWidths = {1, 5, 5};
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(columnWidths);
    table.setWidthPercentage(100);
    table.getDefaultCell().setUseAscender(true);
    table.getDefaultCell().setUseDescender(true);
    Font f = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 13, Font.NORMAL, GrayColor.GRAYWHITE);
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("This is a header", f));
    cell.setBackgroundColor(GrayColor.GRAYBLACK);
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    cell.setColspan(3);
    table.addCell(cell);
    table.getDefaultCell().setBackgroundColor(new GrayColor(0.75f));
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        table.addCell("#");
        table.addCell("Key");
        table.addCell("Value");
    }
    table.setHeaderRows(3);
    table.setFooterRows(1);
    table.getDefaultCell().setBackgroundColor(GrayColor.GRAYWHITE);
    table.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    for (int counter = 1; counter < 101; counter++) {
        table.addCell(String.valueOf(counter));
        table.addCell("key " + counter);
        table.addCell("value " + counter);
    }
    document.add(table);
    document.close();
}
```

It should be fairly simple to adapt this code to C#.

The first problem is solved by defining the column widths at the level of the table. For instance like this (there are other ways to get the same result):

```
float[] columnWidths = {1, 5, 5};
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(columnWidths);
```

The values 1, 5, and 5 aren't absolute widths. As we define the width of the table as 100% of the available width within the margins of the page, iText will divide the available width by 11 (1 + 5 + 5) and the first column will measure 1 time this value, whereas column two and three will measure 5 times this value.

Your second problem can be solved by changing the horizontal alignment. If you work with an explicit `PdfPCell` object, you need to change the value at the cell level, as is done in the following line:

```
cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
```

If you leave it to iText to create the `PdfPCell` object, you need to change the alignment at the level of the *default cell*:

```
table.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
```

Note that the default cell properties are not applied when you add a `PdfPCell` object to the table. In that case, the properties of that `PdfPCell` are used.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I managed to center the cell's text in every column, now I just can't figure out how to make first row to have smallest width...

Here is the code

```
public PdfPTable GetTable(List<hsp_Narudzbe_IzdavanjeFakture4_Result> proizvodi)
    {
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(5);
        table.WidthPercentage = 100F;
        table.DefaultCell.UseAscender = true;
        table.DefaultCell.UseDescender = true;
        Font f = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 13);
        f.Color = BaseColor.WHITE;
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Stavke narudžbe: ", f));
        cell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.BLACK;
        cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        cell.Colspan = 5;
        table.AddCell(cell);
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Redni broj"))
                {
                    VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE,
                    HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER,
                    BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY
                });
            table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Proizvod"))
            {
                VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE,
                HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER,
                BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY
            });
            table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cijena"))
            {
                VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE,
                HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER,
                BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY
            });
            table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Šifra"))
            {
                VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE,
                HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER,
                BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY
            });
            table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Kolicina"))
            {
                VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE,
                HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER,
                BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY
            });
        }
        table.DefaultCell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY;
        table.HeaderRows = 3;
        table.FooterRows = 1;
        int broj = 0;
        table.DeleteLastRow();
        foreach (hsp_Narudzbe_IzdavanjeFakture4_Result p in proizvodi)
        {
            broj++;
            table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(broj.ToString()))
            {
                VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE,
                HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER

            });
            table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(p.Naziv))
            {
                VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE,
                HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER
            });
            table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(p.Cijena))
            {
                VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE,
                HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER
            });
            table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(p.Sifra))
            {
                VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE,
                HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER
            });
            table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(p.Kolicina.ToString()))
            {
                VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE,
                HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER
            });
        }



        return table;
    }
```

Can someone help me figure out how to set the width of each row to a custom size?

Thanks !

Comment: You are overdoing it ;-) Please look at my example. If you let iText create the `PdfPCell`, you can set the alignment and color for the default cell.

Comment: I shall Sir, I have accepted your answer :). Thanks once again!! :D